# Find the minimum $n$ such that $z^n\in(-\infty,0)$

Tags: complex-numbers

Given the complex number $z=$ $1\over i$ $+$ $1\over 1-i$ I have to find the minimum $n$ such that $z^n\in(-\infty,0)$. After a few simplifications I came up with the algebraic form $z=\frac12$$-$$\frac12i$, the modulus $\lvert z\rvert = $$1\over\sqrt2$ and the argument $\theta=-\frac\pi4$. How should I proceed?

Comment: For $z^n \in (-\infty,0)$, the modulus is irrelevant. So look at the argument.

Comment: Note that $z= {1 \over \sqrt{2}} e^{-i { \pi \over 4}}$.

Comment: $z^2=\frac{1}{2^2}(1-i)^2=\frac{1}{4}2i=\frac{1}{2}i\\z^4=(z^2)^2=\frac{1}{4}i^2=-\frac{1}{4}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the argument of $z$ is $-\frac{\pi}{4}$, the argument of $z^n$ will be $-\frac{n\pi}{4}$, up to addition by integer multiples of $2\pi$.

Note that $z^n\in(-\infty,0)\iff \arg(z^n)=\pi$, so we are finding the smallest integer $n$ such that $\pi$ and $-\frac{n\pi}{4}$ differ by a multiple of $2\pi$. You can check and see that this first occurs when $n=4$.

Comment: And what if $z^n\in(0,+\infty)$? Does $arg(z^n) = 2\pi$? Thank you anyway!

Comment: We would say that $\arg(z^n)=0$, in which case we would be searching for the smallest integer $n$ such that $-\frac{n\pi}{4}$ and $0$ differ by a multiple of $2\pi$. This first occurs when $n=8$.